# href not working html

Tags: html

I tried to link a page but href for Home and Login is not working.

```
<div id="menu_wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <ul class="menu" rel="sam1">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu_login"><a href="./login.php">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my code:
[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/misel/fP5RC/2/)

It wont to show me page. A type localhost/index.php in browser and when i try to click on Login i show like it sent me to localhost/index.php#

Comment: Seriously, how do you even expect us to help you here? What error are you getting? 403? 404? 500? Unable to display page? Something else?

Comment: To clarify: You're not asking why jsFiddle gives you a 404 error are you?

Comment: No..i use localhost while i programming in php...and it wont derirect me on login.php which i created and it is in the same folder as index.php

Comment: Maybe change it to `<a href="login.php">Login</a>`

Comment: It's show me the same.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you placed index.php and login.php in the root of your localhost server?

Mine would look like /var/www/myproject/login.php which I would access with http://localhost/myproject/login.php

Answer (score 1):

you can set **[base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)** tag in your *header*:

```
<head>
<base href="http://stackoverflow.com">
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php">base</a>
</body>
```

your link is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/index.php
```

in all **folder** and **subfolder.**

Comment: this worked fine. search problem in your server configuration or source code (if generated with php)